# Field CLS report very good on GA but bad on Search Console. What should I do to fix it?

Tags: core-web-vitals, cumulative-layout-shift, web-vitals

On search console, it says some of my links have bad CLS.

[image]

However, I've been tracking the links for a while and the CLS is perfect (the value is 1000x bigger, according to how the web-vitals client tracks it).

I am using this [official library](https://unpkg.com/web-vitals@3.1.1/dist/web-vitals.iife.js) to track the metrics.

[image]

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Note that your GA is showing an average while the Search Console and Google work of a 75th percentile. On average you may be passing, but Google wants 3 out of 4 page views to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chrome User Experience Report (CrUX) that powers the Core Web Vitals program is collected from real users, but is a lower-level API run in the Chrome Browser that has has access to the full page information.

In contrast JavaScript APIs (as used by RUM solutions - including the web-vitals library) have a more limited view due to security restrictions of web APIs.

This can lead to a [number of differences](https://web.dev/crux-and-rum-differences/), in particular for any iframes that impact the CWVs as Web APIs cannot peer into iframes to get those details.

However, the user won’t know these are iframes (unless they’re a web developer and go looking!) so they do count as the user experience of the top-level page and hence why CrUX measure them.

This is just a limitation unfortunately for good security reasons.

Does your web page have iframes? Either for other pages on your site, or by embedding third-party content like videos?

Comment: Thanks very much for your information. I don't create any iframes on purpose but I use Adsense and I am sure the ads are injected as iframes. I never thought ads will be the cause because they were usually raw text or static images. However, I do see some animation and interactions in recent ads now. Would that be the cause?

Comment: It could be. The Performance panel and the Performance Insights panel of Dev Tools does have some visibility into lay out shifts across iframes so worth running a load trace in there and seeing if it seems them. Or if not, then a fuller trace beyond load while scrolling and interacting with the page to see if that triggers some shifts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If there's penalty caused by the iframes, do I have any way to fix it? Technically: do some JavaScript magic on the iframes, or non-technically: It'd be great if Google could filter the ads for Web Vitals score also, for instance, I can filter out the bad ads, even though I will lose some revenue.

Comment: Not that I'm aware off. The iframe is basically it's own world (though does impact the user hence why it counts) so you have limited scope into them. But I'd find out if that is the case here before you worry too much about it. It could be something else (your GA is incorrect, or extensions, or something completely else!).

Comment: One other option might be to remove the ads from one page, and see if the CLS issues disappear from that page. You'll need a page popular enough to be tracked separately in CrUX.

Comment: Thanks! `You'll need a page popular enough to be tracked separately in CrUX` - any criteria of that? like DAU or session duration?

Comment: We don't give specific criteria for that: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/methodology/#eligibility. Best would be to plug a URL into PageSpeed Insights and see it returns URL-level data or gives a warning it fell back to origin-level data. Then make the change, and wait the 28-days for it to fully take effect, and check PSI again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, I will fix it with your advices.